# Animate resize by clicking on a link instead of the item being resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm just starting to learn javascript so I'd appreciate if someone could help me with this.

I currently have a resize animation that happens when the iframe itself is clicked. I would like to modify it, so that the resize happens when the "resize" link is clicked, as supposed to the iframe itself but I cannot get it work.

Thanks in advance

```js
$("iframe").click(function () {
    var p = $(this).parent();
    p.append('<iframe src="' + $(this).attr("src") +
             '" alt="' + $(this).attr("alt") + '" class="preview" />');
    var i = $("iframe.preview", p);
    var maxWidth = i.width();
    var maxHeight = i.height();
    i.css({ width: $(this).width(), height: $(this).height() });
    i.css({ top: $(this).position().top, left: $(this).position().left });
    i.show();
    i.animate({ marginTop: -((maxHeight / 2) - (i.height() / 2)),
                marginLeft: -((maxWidth / 2) - (i.width() / 2)),
                width: maxWidth,
                height: maxHeight }, 800);
    return false;
});
```

```css
html, body {
height:100%;
text-align:center;
}

iframe {
  margin:0 auto;
  border:#444 40px solid;
  border-radius:30px;
}

#resize {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

.preview {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 524px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="resize" href="#">resize</a>

<iframe src="https://css-tricks.com" align="middle" frameborder="0" style="width: 768px; height: 524px;"></iframe>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$("iframe").click(...)` to `$("a").click(...)`, or by its id: `$("#resize").click(...)` (which is better, because the former would attach a click event handler to ALL of the `<a>`s in the page.

Comment: using `$("#resize").click(...)` creates a resizing iframe at the position of the link instead of resizing the original iframe